# Python how make for loop with variation i*2

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to make a for loop like:

```
for (i=2; i<200; i*=2){
}
```

in `python`. How can I do that? with `range`?

Comment: @Jason That does not address the question.  Read it again.

Comment: `for (i=0; i<200; i*=2) { }` ... really? `i` never changes!

Comment: @TomKarzes just fixed! with i=2, you are right! thanks

Comment: @ReblochonMasque just fixed! thanks for notice that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `while`:

```
i = 2
while i < 200:
    print i
    i *= 2
```

It produces following output:

```
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use left bit shift (instead of *2) and a while loop:

```
i = 2
while i < 200:
    ... #something
    i <<= 1
```

The *2 variation would still be valid though

```
i = 2
while i < 200:
    ... #something
    i *= 2
```

A more fanciful variation (may not be as efficient as while loop with << 1 though) using for loop would be something like this:

```
for i in [2**(j + 1) for j in range(int(math.log(200,2))]:
```

I would still go with the while loop though...

**Original comment:**

That being said, if i started from 0, the loop will end with infinite loop if the value is not changed before *2 or << 1 (note @TomKarzes comment)

Comment: Of course, both of these loops are infinite, with `i` remaining `0` the entire time (as was OP's original loop).  But I assume that isn't what OP intended.

Comment: @TomKarzes from the OP given for loop structure alone, that's true. Thanks, I put up a note about that...

Comment: yeah I just fixed this issue

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use a `while` loop.  If you want to use a `for` loop, define your own function:

```
def mul_range(start, stop=None, step=2):
    if stop is None:
        start, stop = 2, start
    while start < stop or step < 1 and start > stop:
        yield start
        start *= step
```

You can then use `mul_range()` similarly to how you use `range()`:

```
>>> for num in mul_range(1, 400, 2):
...     print(num)
...
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
>>> for num in mul_range(100):
...     print(num)
...
2
4
8
16
32
64
>>>
```

It even works with fractions:

```
>>> for num in mul_range(8, 1, 0.5):
...     print(num)
...
8
4.0
2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional technique using `itertools` and `operator`:

```
import itertools as it
import operator as op

limit = 200
for i in it.takewhile(limit.__gt__, it.accumulate(it.repeat(2), op.mul)):
    print(i)
```